# Issue with bluetooth connection of an application

Tags: bluetooth

I tried to run the FloorboardFX application on Ubuntu 23.04.

This application is supposed to connect to a Bluetooth device which controls a Guitar Amp, however the Bluetooth connection fails. I did try running it with sudo and without.

Can it be that the Application needs extra rights to access the Bluetooth hardware or that my user needs certain rights?

I attached the Terminal output as well. If any further information is needed, let me know. It would be nice to find a solution to this issue.

[image: Terminal output]